# Problem downloading the last DirectX SDK

Tags: sdk, download, directx

I can't manage to download the last version of the DirectX SDK (june 2010) : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3021d52b-514e-41d3-ad02-438a3ba730ba&displaylang=en

When I try to install it by double clicking the *DXSDK_June10.exe* I get the following message:

[DirectX SDK error http://erytmo.dubbing-brothers.com/download/directxsdkerror.png](http://erytmo.dubbing-brothers.com/download/directxsdkerror.png)

It seems that the file is corrupted. Is there another way to download this SDK?

Comment: Try running it `/?` - you may be able to unpack it manually to get the setup image. You can probably download it from MSDN if you have access but otherwise I expect you've just had a bad download and try again?

Comment: What do you mean by "try running it"? You mean the packer tool?
I tried download the file DXSDK_June10.exe several times but it always fails as described.

Comment: I think I've seen that before.. Hmm, I think it was solved by simply trying to download it in another browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download DirectX from my home and transfer it it was no problem to install it. It seems the firewall of my company corrupt the download: the good file was 599 452 800 bytes versus 599373885 bytes for the bad one.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file size of what you downloaded.  You probably just need to re-download it.

I just ran into this problem, then I looked at my file size, and it was only 300MB instead of 500+MB, so somehow the download had been interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Their server is to slow. So typical for Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Copy DXSDK_June10.exe file to "C:\" .
2) Run DXSDK_June10.exe .
```

That's all.